# Mismatch of address on passport with passport of parents

Tags: passports

The address on my passport is different from my parents' and brother's in spelling. I am 20 years old.

Will this impair my travels in the future?

Comment: what country? Is the address on the page with your picture and other official details?

Comment: my country name is India. yes ,addres of place of birth is mentioned on that page which is also different in spelling from my parents and brothers passport. so tell me whether it will cause discrepancy in future. thank u for ansrs

Answer (score 4):

The [ICAO Standard for Passports](http://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p4_cons_en.pdf) identifies all the fields that appear on the "id page" (the page that has your photo) and it does not include a place for your address; but rather your *place of birth*.

So unless you have a very old passport (which I suggest you get renewed), you should not even have an address field on your passport to worry about.

Comment: +1.  Immigration does not care about your home address, it's not even included in the biometric data.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I'd like to add that some recent passports indeed do contain information about where the holder is domiciled. As an example, German passports have a field for the city of residence (no complete address). However, in that case, the city is not part of the "data page" but it is only written later (page 2) in the passport (so that it can be changed by the respective authority when you move). We don't know the OP's citizenship, though.

Comment: Canadian passports have a page after the ID where you can write in your own address yourself, I think mostly so people could return a lost passport to you. I've never noticed anyone looking at it when they peruse my passport.

Comment: @KateGregory The UK ones a section where you can write in name + address of family members as emergency contact details. This has caused me minor issues in India, as people have expected to find *my* address in my passport, found my parents address in the emergency contact section, seen the surname match and then treated that as my "official" address...

Comment: USA passports (at least, as of ~8 years ago) have fields on a separate page from the photo for address and contact information, that are recommended but optional, and which can be changed when you move or want a different emergency contact. I think I filled mine in with pencil(!), the easier to change.